# Facebook API events fire continuously

Tags: facebook, events

I am using the following example from the facebook website to have a user logon and get his details: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/481

I am encountering two problems:
1) The auth.sessionChange event gets fired every half a second, and the page reloads accordingly every half a second (because of this code: FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
  window.location.reload();
});)
2) When the user clicks login, the login windows doesn't close upon successful login - but nothing happens instead.. After logging in in the popup window, the login page turns into a white blank page..

Answer (score 0):

In your Application Settings, make sure you set your Site URL and Site Domain.

Did you also make sure to update the App Id from your Applications settings in the code?

Last, are you using Safari that could possibly have session caching or cookies disabled? Having done a bunch of Facebook Applications, I can tell you that if you have cookies disabled, you're in some trouble.

I just went through the example, copy-pasted, created a test app, and it works perfectly (tested in Chrome.) Open up Charles, and make sure it's connecting to facebook.com/extern/login_status.php with the proper app id.